# Using OpenGL (libGL.so) with EGL context

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, egl, glx

As far as I know, GLES (libGLES) can work on EGL context and OpenGL (libGL.so) can work on GLX context.

Is it possible to use openGL functions in libGL.so with EGL context?

Or is there any theoretical or practical reason that this can not be done without big effort?

I'm considering the Intel HD graphics, so I can build libGL.so and libEGL out of MESA source code.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to use openGL functions in libGL.so with EGL context?

In principle:

[`eglBindAPI()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglBindAPI.xhtml):

> `EGLBoolean eglBindAPI(EGLenum api);`
>
> ...
>
> If `api` is `EGL_OPENGL_API`, the current rendering API is set to the **OpenGL API**.

But note:

> `EGL_BAD_PARAMETER` is generated ... if the specified client API is not supported by the EGL implementation.